# Migrating working project from Eclipse to IntelliJ IDEA gives exception on loading Centipede

Tags: java, intellij-idea

This is the error message I got when I imported a working project that I created in Eclipse to IntelliJ IDEA. Has anyone seen this before?

```
load: Centipede can't be instantiated.
java.lang.InstantiationException: Centipede
at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:427)
at sun.applet.AppletPanel.createApplet(AppletPanel.java:799)
at sun.applet.AppletPanel.runLoader(AppletPanel.java:728)
at sun.applet.AppletPanel.run(AppletPanel.java:378)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: Centipede.<init>()
at java.lang.Class.getConstructor0(Class.java:3082)
at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:412)
... 4 more
```

Would greatly appreciate someones help!

Comment: Title should reflect and summarize the main issue.

Comment: Do you get the exception on attempt to run the project? Does the class `Centipede` have default constructor (with no parameters)? Try also rebuilding the project before run.

Comment: sorry @dirkgroten I'll do better next time

Comment: @andrey thanks for the comment. I havent looked at java in a long time and just know the basics. I chose the wrong applet class to run the project.